# Assertions and constraints

Tags: configuration, configuration-management, linting

I'm constructing a template to build a configuration file, and the service that consumes this file places constraints on identifier lengths.

If an identifier is longer than, say, 6 characters, the service will get part-way through applying the configuration, fail, and leave the node in an inconsistent state.

How can I perform an assertion to trigger a deployment transaction failure, preventing the target nodes' service from being misconfigured?

My particular circumstance is Salt, but I would be curious to see how other systems solve the problem as well.

Comment: Well in chef I'll add a linting rule,  either rspec or foodcritic or ensure the identifier match in the recipe.  No idea for salt,  I don't think there's a gerenic answer as each configuration manager has its own specificity

Comment: I'll edit the answer to be a bit less specific.

Comment: At the moment, my current contemplation for a Saltstack+Jinja solution would be a macro that attempts to read from a file that cannot exist. Other renderers would work differently. A Python renderer, for example, would be trivial; simply throw an exception.

Answer (score 7):

In Ansible: you can use `assert` or `fail` module.

```
- name: "Make sure web_sites is dictionary"
  fail: msg="web_sites should be dictionary"
  when: web_sites is not dict  


- name: "cluster_name should be shorter than 6 chars"
  assert: 
       that: cluster_name|len <= 6
```

In Puppet: there is [fail](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/function.html#fail) function evaluated during parsing phase which cause parsing failure on server (see [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570957/is-it-possible-to-assert-in-puppet))

```
 if length($cluster_name) > 6 {
      fail("Cluster name is too long. Should be less than 6 chars.")
 }
```